# 10 digit numbers to be extracted from data on fixed rows on Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, extract, phone-number

I need to extract 10 digit numbers from data sets on individual rows

The position of each row in the sheet is to remain the same.

When multiple 10 digit numbers are available on row needs to come together in a single cell with comma.

sharing a screenshot [image: Google sheet] and link to Google sheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oDWK_QCSDU7JTjG3haNIWfx1R4w0tUu2msasqjmHrM4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
B2 → =IFERROR(JOIN(", ",FILTER(FLATTEN(C2:O2),LEN(FLATTEN(C2:O2))=10)))
B3 → =IFERROR(JOIN(", ",FILTER(FLATTEN(C3:O3),LEN(FLATTEN(C3:O3))=10)))
B4 → =IFERROR(JOIN(", ",FILTER(FLATTEN(C4:O4),LEN(FLATTEN(C4:O4))=10)))
B5 → =IFERROR(JOIN(", ",FILTER(FLATTEN(C5:O5),LEN(FLATTEN(C5:O5))=10)))
B6 → =IFERROR(JOIN(", ",FILTER(FLATTEN(C6:O6),LEN(FLATTEN(C6:O6))=10)))
```

And so on...

[image]

#### Reference:

- [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en)
- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en)
- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

Comment: If you don't want them all together and you need them listed in separate columns and because they are of different sizes, then you need to use a formula for each column. I've added the examples to use in each column in the answer.

Comment: If you are not in the answer to your need, add the question as the result expected by you would be, thus facilitating the visualization.

Comment: Add the expected result in the question and in the spreadsheet, thus making it easier to see what you want.

Comment: Hi Brondby, I edited the Q and the spread sheet :)

Comment: See if the new model solves your problem.